# An Iterated Map on Natural Numbers and its orbits

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Define a function $f_k:\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ by $$f_k(x) = \begin{cases}
 x+k, & \text{ if } x \text{ is prime};\\ 
\text{largest prime factor of }x, & \text{ if }x \text{ is composite.}\\
\end{cases}$$

Consider the sequence $S(x_0,k)=\{f_k(x_0),f_k(f_k(x_0)),f_k(f_k(f_k(x_0))),\ldots\}$, i.e., $S(x_0,k)=\{f_k(x_0),f^2_k(x_0),f^3_k(x_0),\ldots\}$. I have two observations:

1. For all $x_0 \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ and for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence $S(x_0,k)$ is eventually periodic.
2. By suitably choosing $x_0$ and $k$, we can achieve any period, i.e., for all $l\geq 2$, there exists $x_0,k$ such that $S(x_0,k)$ is eventually periodic with period $l$.

My question is how to prove these two observations? Any hint will be of much help.

Comment: Part of me thinks maybe Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic sequences in primes could be helpful. Or perhaps the fact that any arithmetic progression will eventually--often rapidly--find a number whose only only factors are $2,3,5$, meaning starting with large numbers will still cause many/most starting points to fall to small numbers. Some quick empirical work, however, suggests that (2) won't hold up. Most values of $k$ find the same cycle length for the majority of values of $x_0$. Some have two different ones (and most but not all can give cycle length $2$ if $k \mid x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Dirichlet's theorem. Now, I also believe that the periodicity has something to do with it. However, I still feel that observation 2 is correct. I have checked for lengths $l=2$ upto $17$. Say for $l=5$, take $S(2,5)$, for $l=6$, take $S(3,4)$, for $l=7$, take $S(2,9)$, and so on. However, what I noticed empirically that for getting large values of $l$, we need large values of $k$.

Comment: I actually took the calcs out a bit farther, and I'm now convinced that (2) is likely correct. It just seems like the smallest $l$ not generated by the values in $2 < k < K$ runs something like $l \sim k^{1/3}$

Comment: Can you please explain how you are getting $l\sim k^{1/3}$?

Comment: Sorry, that "something like" was doing heavy lifting there. That's not a calculation but a guesstimate.